# Unique Constraint depending on value of a field

Tags: mysql, symfony, unique-constraint

I need to create a unique constraint for my subscription table for not allowing a user to have two active subscriptions at the same time. I created the migration and updated my entity class:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_user_id_status ON user_subscription_plan (user_id, status)
```

But I just realised that the status field can have multiple values (active, inactive, processed) so I should probably have this constraint only when two statuses are active, but I can have two processed ones for example. Is it correct? Then how do I do that on the entity class? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: having history/log records in the same table as the "live" data is rarely working well with unique constraints. Working with *transactions*, you could ensure that only one user_id has a certain status. However, when money is involved, why would you disallow multiple active subscription plans? ^^ btw: having a unique constraint fail might kill the entity manager's connection and make your life harder, so instead of a dysfunctional unique constraint on your possibly inappropriate database schema, you might want to restructure...

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: @Littlefoot Mysql

Comment: Even if having such a constraint on the database is not a bad idea, it could be easier to check this within your application (in PHP code)

Comment: You could do it with symfony constraint, but we would need your entities to guide you with it

Comment: @NicoHaase do I need to use listeners, #postUpdate #postPersist? or can I just check when it tries to add it in the database?

Comment: @DylanKAS is there any documentation perhaps somewhere so I can figure it out by myself? or at least the main idea

Comment: Just type "symfony constraint" on google and try to look for constraints that would work with what you are doing. If there is none, then create your own constraint (quite easy only need to add 2 classes)

Answer (score 1):

As you use MySQL, see if *function-based index* helps.

```
create table test (user_id int, status varchar(20));

create unique index ui1_test on test
  (user_id, (case when status = 'active' then status end));
```

It won't let you insert two rows whose status is `active`, but won't prevent you on inserting as many rows as you want with any other status (you mentioned `inactive` and `processed`).

Have a look at [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lGLf-ByE) for demonstration.